# pass state to functional component without using props

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is there a way to access state in a functional component without passing in props? I have a component which passes a default set of props, and I am not able to add to or edit to this list of props (it's part of a third-party plugin, so this makes sense). I know I could use redux to set/access the variable, but I would prefer not to do this, as it is information that would not otherwise need to be in redux.

Here's information on the third party component, and other people with similar issues: 
https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/issues/844

Comment: Tough to give a specific suggestion without an example of what you're trying to accomplish, but if you don't want to pass props or use Redux, the only other way for sharing information between components I can think of would be the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: HOC will do, if you know the classes at the same place you pass the currencyformatter.